# Как создать словарь в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужен словарь, в который добавится ключ, а его значение будет другой словарь, в который будут добавляться другие ключи со значениями. Пробовал делать такой код в функции:

```
dict['key'] = {key:value}
```

Но в итоге создаётся словарь, в котором значение это словарь, которое не добавляет новых ключей в словаре внутри. Пример: 'key':{'key1':'value1'}, т.е. заменяет последним значением-словарём, а нужно чтобы добавляло: 'key':{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}

Comment: Ничего непонятно, в вашем примере `dict['key']['key2'] = 'value2'` будет всё отлично добавлять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключами словаря могут быть только шифруемые объекты: числа, строки, картежи и frozenset. Если индексировать словари другими словарями, то при изменении словаря, который является ключем потеряется возможность извлечь его значение поскольку изменится его хеш. Если в словаре необходимо сохранить другой словарь, то пожалуйста. Они гетерогенны по своей природе

```
In [1]: d = {'foo': 'bar'}
In [2]: d2 = {'dict': d}
In [3]: d2.items()
Out[3]: dict_items([('dict', {'foo': 'bar'})])
```

Или тоже самое в форме литерала

```
In [1]: d = {'spam': {'foo': 'bar'}}
In [2]: d.items()
Out[2]: dict_items([('spam', {'foo': 'bar'})])
```

Comment: Только не шифруемые, а хешируемые )

Answer (score 1):

Примеры наполнения словаря, в котором значения являются также словарями:

```
t = {1: 1}
print(t)
t.update({2: {21: 22}, 3: {31: 33}})
print(t)
t.update([[4,{40: 41}],[5, {54: 55}]])
print(t)
t.setdefault(6)
print(t)
t.setdefault(7, {71: 72})
print(t)
# {1: 1}
# {1: 1, 2: {21: 22}, 3: {31: 33}}
# {1: 1, 2: {21: 22}, 3: {31: 33}, 4: {40: 41}, 5: {54: 55}}
# {1: 1, 2: {21: 22}, 3: {31: 33}, 4: {40: 41}, 5: {54: 55}, 6: None}
# {1: 1, 2: {21: 22}, 3: {31: 33}, 4: {40: 41}, 5: {54: 55}, 6: None, 7: {71: 72}}
```

Обращение к словарю-значению осуществляется через двойное указание ключей:

```
w = {"1": {"11": 11}, "2": {"22": 22}}
print(w["1"]["11"])
```

Обратиться к словарю-значению без "словарного" ключа не получиться:

```
print(w["11"])
KeyError: "11"
```

Если вам необходимо обращаться именно к элементам словарей внутри, можно пересобрать словарь и обращаться прямо:

```
new_w = {}
for s in w.values():
    new_w.update(**s)
print(new_w)
print(new_w["22"])
# {'11': 11, '22': 22}
# 22
```

Comment: Смотрите на метку вопроса, там указан третий питон, а у вас код для второго питона. Разница видна -- во втором print это оператор, в третьем -- функция.

Comment: спс, добавил скобочек